# Difference netween Step Out and Call Stack

Tags: c#, debugging

When I put a break point in my program and execution stops there, then what is the difference between clicking on Step Out in Debug window and viewing the call stack?

Comment: This implies you view them as almost the same thing, which is very confusing to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i have wrote about call stack window in debug mode might help you to get info about cal stack window : [Help yourself in Debugging by using Call Stack and Immediate Window](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2011/06/help-yourself-in-debugging-by-using.html)

**call Stack window** : you will get information about the method get called, what is parameter value, line no of the method in file, is it external call or internal, programming language in which method written.

**Step Out** on the Debug menu to resume running on the target. This command executes the rest of the current function and breaks when the function return is completed.

**Step Out** is related when you are debugging inside a method. If you press the Shift - F11 within the current method, then the execution will complete the execution of the method and will pause at the next statement from where it called.

[Mastering Debugging in Visual Studio 2010 - A Beginner's Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Answer (score 2):

One runs the program until it steps out of the current function, the other shows you the call stack.